# google maps javascript API - gray map when hiding and showing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I was having an issue with google maps javascript API returning an empty gray box except for the google logo.  I probably would have gotten the UI too, though, if I didn't disable that.  I couldn't for the life of me figure out what the issue was, because my test example was working fine, but then I realized it was because I was hiding and showing the div with jquery in my actual project.  My fix was to keep it active behind other divs and simply hide those when I'm ready to see the map, but I was wondering if there is a better solution.  I'm still not sure why exactly hiding the div and showing it later would cause it to be blank, while leaving it active the whole time works.

Comment: I hope this isn't "noise", but may I ask why the down vote?  This is a unique version of the gray map question as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to redraw map after show/hide again using javascript `setTimeout`  function

Answer (score 1):

try to

setTimeout(function() { map.invalidateSize() }, 900);